# Cannot create files in while loop with Visual Basic 7

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access, while-loop

When I create a file outside a while-loop is working fine as following:

```
Set oFileSip = fso.CreateTextFile(strUriMetadata, True)    
While (Not rs.EOF)
   rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

When I try to create file in the loop as following, I ge ***Permission denied (Error 70)***

```
While (Not rs.EOF)
   Set oFileSip = fso.CreateTextFile(strUriMetadata, True)
   rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

Why do I get "permission denied" when I create file in the loop? How can fix this? Thanx!

Comment: Does this happen the first or second time through the loop?

Answer (score 2):

`ofileSip` is a `TextStream` and if you put it into a loop like you do then you try to access an "open" textstream when looping the second time.

You need to close it first like that

```
Do while (Not rs.EOF)
    Set oFileSip = fso.CreateTextFile(strUriMetadata, True)
    ' further code
    oFileSip.Close
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

IMO you should also change the name of the file when looping otherwise you will always create an new empty file with the same name over and over again.

Comment: Thank you Storax. I did as you suggested  oFileSip.Close in the loop but still get exactly the same error Permission denied (Error 70).

Comment: And there is no other stream open for this file resp. the file has not been opened in another application?